# Making an Ignite gallery mobile friendly

Tags: html, css, mobile, joomla, responsive-design

In the process of making a website mobile friendly, but not sure what's stopping an Ignite Image gallery from shrinking.

I've tried changing all of the widths on the containing  tags, and the image itself to max-width but it doesn't seem to have made any difference.

The url is: http://discus-music.co.uk/juxtavoices#!Juxtavoices_36

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image has an inline max-width of 870px.  If you give it an explicit percentage width of X% it will flow.  You could set this:

```
.large_img img {width: 100%; position: relative;}
```

Comment: I've tried removing the inline width in the inspector, but when i set a width:100%; on the img it appears 10 pixels wide for some reason, regardless of whether a max-width is declared also.

Comment: fixed this by changing the image to position:relative;

Comment: Bingo!! well done I've updated my answer so this can help others with a similar problem